# Django QuerySet attribute as Float instead of Unicode

Tags: django, mongodb, python-2.7, scrapy, mongoengine

We are making a Pc builder compare website, so you can compare pc components prices and make a cheap pc. We are using external data with Scrapy that saves it into MongoDB, we use Django as framework.

I have a 'prijs' Array (price) of an object as unicode, this object is in the QuerySet. I want that each 'prijs' in that array is a Float instead of unicode. Is there some way to convert the unicode array to a normal float array. I Googled alot but no solution for me, I hope you can help me with our problem.

Sorry for my bad English, thanks in advance!

---

Here is one object of MongoDB:

```
> db.processoren.findOne()

{
"_id" : ObjectId("547db39af2125f612cb8a1e5"),
"info" : [
    "Quad-core, Inclusief koeler"
],
"sku" : [
    "BX80646I54590"
],
"prijs" : [
    "188.00000000000000000000"
],
"categorie" : "processoren",
"herkomst" : "paradigit",
"naam" : [
    "Intel Core i5-4590 - 3.3GHz - Socket 1150"
],
"link" : "http://www.paradigit.nl/intel-core-i5-4590-3-3ghz-socket-1150/80015736/details.aspx",
"stock" : [
    "Op dit moment niet beschikbaar"
]
}
```

---

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *
from APc.settings import DBNAME

connect(DBNAME)

class Processoren(Document):

    herkomst = StringField(max_length=200)
    categorie = StringField(max_length=120)
    naam = StringField(max_length=500)
    subnaam = StringField(max_length=500)
    info = StringField(max_length=500)
    prijs = FloatField()
    stock = StringField(max_length=500)

    ean = StringField(max_length=200)
    sku = StringField(max_length=200)
    herkomst = StringField(max_length=200)  
    link = StringField(max_length=200)
```

---

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from bson.json_util import dumps
from pcbuilder.compatibility import *
from pcbuilder.filters import *
import json as simplejson
from models import Processoren, Moederborden, Koeling, Behuizingen, Grafische, Harde, Dvd, Geheugen, Voeding
from itertools import chain
import json

def processoren(request):

    processorenlijst = Processoren.objects

    print type(processorenlijst[0].prijs[0])
```

---

This is the output of the print

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a list of strings to floats by doing something like below.

```
unicode_list = [u'10', u'20', u'123.1']
[float(val) for val in unicode_list]
```

I've never used MongoDB but I know in db backends like MySQL and PSQL you enforce types. The ORM will then return the values as the correct types. Perhaps the real issue is the structure of your data.